# Inplace recursive Quicksort

Tags: algorithm, memory, recursion, quicksort, performance

I have read that recursive implementation of QuickSort will require O(log n) of additional space. Why would that be?

Is that due to stack space?

Comment: Yes. You can avoid recursion, but you still need a stack with a depth around log N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed that would be down to the stack space for the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

It can be considered due to stack space ,also in every recursion you are dividing your array into two parts which for the whole process takes log N time which is quite unavoidable....

Answer (score 0):

O(log n) is nothing - just pointers requires such amount of memory.